# Dependency in WPF custom control

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I am writing a WPF custom control extended from Listbox. In the control I have a border which I need to size with some specific logic. This logic is embedded in another class(different library) i.e. this custom control has a dependency. So

1.Should I inject this dependency by writing a Dependency property in the Control and then assigning this property the object which encapsulated the logic or

2.Custom control should not be dependent on any library
        in this case I have to duplicate the logic.

Comment: I havent understood your question but there are few rules you should stick to when programming such as do not repeat yourself. Therefore I take no1. :D :D :D

Comment: thanks Dev but user control should not be Dependent on any external dependencies. so not sure about my first option

Comment: user control may be dependent on external assembies, who says it may not? if you write a user control that allows to edit a pupil means you will end up having few textboxes in it of course you may reference the business entity pupil if needed which for example is in another assembly called business entities. or another example if user control has its theme in another external resource of course you may reference it, why not?

Comment: Sorry dev my bad, I didn't mean 'User control' I wanted to say 'Custom control' in my earlier post and 'Custom control' should be stand alone. But in 'User controls' respect you are correct.

Comment: Ok I see. Yes CUSTOM CONTROL shall be a stand-alone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that you can answer your own question... imagine this scenario: You go with option 1. Now what does your `CustomControl` do if a user of the control does *not* supply that property? I could be wrong, but it seems as though you would still need to provide a default implementation of your functionality in this instance... which could point to your second option being more straight forward.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Sheridan. I think I will provide a default implementation. The custom control will be used within the organization so it should be OK.